# Javascript -Setting up collision in a Canvas Array Grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, collision, maze

I'm working on a maze game for a college project and I found myself stuck on setting up a way to prevent it going through the 1's in the array grid. The player moves fine through the array, just no collision

```
let maze;
let recx = 17;
let recy = 0;
let dy = 1;
let dx = 1;
let canvas;
let ctx;
let HEIGHT = 500;
let WIDTH = 900;
let blockSize = 50;
let collision = 0;
function Maze()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    maze = 
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    ];

    
    for(let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++)
    {
        for(let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++)
        {
            if(maze[y][x] === 1)
            {
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.fillRect(x*50, y*50, blockSize, blockSize);
            }
            else if(maze [y][x] === -1)
            {
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                ctx.fillRect(x*50, y*50, blockSize, blockSize)
            }
        }
    }
};

function playerInit()
{
    for(let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++)
    {
        for(let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++)
        {
            clear();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(recx*50,recy*50,blockSize,blockSize);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

        }
    }
};

function clear()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    Maze();
};
function checkcollision()
{
    for(let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++)
    {
        for(let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++)
        { 
            if(maze[y][x] === 1)
            {
                collision = 1;
            }
        }
    }
};
function doKeyDown(evt)
{
    switch (evt.keyCode) 
    {
        case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed */
        if (recy*50 - dy*50 >= 0)
        {
            recy -= dy;
            clear();
            checkcollision();
            if (collision === 1)
            {
            recy += dy;
            collision = 0;
            clear();
            }
        }

    break;
        case 40:  /* Down arrow was pressed */
        if (recy*50 + dy*50 < HEIGHT )
        {
            recy += dy;
            clear();
            checkcollision();
            if (collision === 1)
            {
            recy -= dy;
            collision = 0;
            clear();
            }
        }

    break;
        case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressed */
        if (recx*50 - dx*50 >= 0)
        {
            recx -= dx;
            clear();
            checkcollision();
            if (collision === 1)
            {
            recx += dx;
            collision = 0;
            clear();
            }
        }
    break;
        case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed */
        if ((recx*50 + dx*50 < WIDTH))
        {
            recx += dx;
            clear();
            checkcollision();
            if (collision === 1)
            {
            recx -= dx;
            collision = 0;
            clear();
            }
        }
    break;
    }
  
};
window.onload = () => 
{
    Maze();
    playerInit();
    window.setInterval(playerInit, 10);
    window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
};
```

The collision info that is in the checkcollision function and in the dokeydown event is placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out a couple of things. When creating a player it is best to create in in such a way that it is an object with keys that can be accessed. I have removed the function that created you player rectangle and am using a class object instead. This gives me access to the x and y values and makes it easier to change.

I also removed the `setInterval` and have replaced it with `requestAnimationFrame`. This runs at the FPS of the device. I however did keep you `clear()` function so the map itself only gets cleared and re-drawn when an arrowkey is pressed like you had it before.

The collision detection isn't really checking for collision but rather checking if the adjacent cell is a 1. If it is then the `doKeyDown` function will just return and not let the player move. This works great for a simple map like this especially when you are moving cell by cell.

I did my best to leave the code mainly yours so you can better understand it. I did have to add width and height for the canvas so if you were doing that via CSS then you'll want to delete those lines below your ctx variable.

```js
let maze;
let recx = 17;
let recy = 0;
let dy = 1;
let dx = 1;
let canvas;
let ctx;
let HEIGHT = 500;
let WIDTH = 900;
let blockSize = 50;
let collisionArray = [];
let cantGoLeft = false;
let cantGoDown = false;
let cantGoRight = false;
let cantGoUp = false;
function Maze() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = WIDTH;
  canvas.height = HEIGHT;
  maze = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
  ];

  for (let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++) {
      if (maze[y][x] === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x * 50, y * 50, blockSize, blockSize);
      } else if (maze[y][x] === -1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(x * 50, y * 50, blockSize, blockSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.x = recx * 50 + 1;
    this.y = recy * 50 + 1;
    //This.index returns the actual index number in the
    //tilemap array that the player is in. We can use this
    //to see where it is in relation to the tiles
    this.index = Math.trunc((this.y * 18 + this.x) / blockSize);
    this.width = blockSize - 2;
    this.height = blockSize - 2;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  update() {
    //since the constructor is only loaded in a static state we 
    //require a function that continupusly updates parameters.
    this.x = recx * 50 + 1;
    this.y = recy * 50 + 1;
    this.index = Math.trunc((this.y * 18 + this.x) / blockSize);
   
  }
}
//This just creates a new instance of the player
let player = new Player();

//Not really collision detection but it works for simple maps
//like this.
function collisionDetection() {
  for (let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++) {
      //again creating an object with key:value pairs allows us 
      //to control and access the cell better, just like the player
      let cell = { x: x, y: y, index: y * 18 + x, val: maze[y][x] };
      //This says that if the index to the left of the player == 1
      //then change cantGoLeft to true. This gets used in your doKeyDown function
      if (player.index - 1 == cell.index && cell.val == 1) {
        cantGoLeft = true;
      }
      else if (player.index - 1 == cell.index && cell.val == 0){
        cantGoLeft = false;
      }
      
      if (player.index + 1 == cell.index && cell.val == 1) {
        cantGoRight = true;
      }
      else if (player.index + 1 == cell.index && cell.val == 0){
        cantGoRight = false;
      }
      
      if (player.index + 18 == cell.index && cell.val == 1 || player.index + 18 > 180) {
        cantGoDown = true;
      }
      else if (player.index + 18 == cell.index && cell.val == 0){
        cantGoDown = false;
      }
      
       if (player.index - 18 == cell.index && cell.val == 1 || player.index - 18 < 0) {
        cantGoUp = true;
      }
      else if (player.index - 18 == cell.index && cell.val == 0){
        cantGoUp = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function doKeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 38 /* Up arrow was pressed */:
      //if cantGoUp is true then it returns and no further actions are taken
      if (cantGoUp) { 
        return
      } else {
        recy -= 1;
      }
      clear();
      break;
    case 40 /* Down arrow was pressed */:
      //same as above except down
      if (cantGoDown) {
        return
      } else {
        recy += 1;
      }
      clear();
      break;
    case 37 /* Left arrow was pressed */:
      if (cantGoLeft) {
        return;
      } else {
        recx -= 1;
      }
      clear();
      break;
    case 39 /* Right arrow was pressed */:
      if (cantGoRight) {
        return
      } else {
        recx += dx;
      }
      clear();
      break;
  }
}
Maze(); //called once on load

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  Maze();
}

function animate() {
  player.update();
  player.draw();
  collisionDetection();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate); //continuously calls this function
}
animate();

window.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```